# HDFS single node replication

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

When running a single-node HDFS cluster (or pseudo-distributed mode) with several data directories on separate physical hard disk drives, is it possible to have block replication in case of a disk failure?

I understand that single-node installations are atypical but still would like to know. Everything I read only dealt with node failures but I could find nothing about disk failures in single-node scenarios.

**Note :** I'm only interested in the possibility of data loss here, not in the availability of the so-called "cluster".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node failure can be caused just by a disk failure, so every disk failure will cause a node failure which means that the data will be lost if you have a single disk and single node. But if you have two disks on a node you can have two DataNodes on that machine each with a separate disk and then you can have replication. In this case disk failure will not cause a node failure necessarily.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer. By two slaves, do you mean I should somehow run two separate DataNode instances on the same machine with one disk each, or is running a single DataNode instance sufficient to ensure no data loss? Note: I'm not interested in cluster availability here, only in the possibility of data loss.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my answer Yes, I mean two DataNodes on a machine with two disks